# Cannot set property 'value' of null when setting value in input

Tags: javascript, html

My script has error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null`
I want to set value to input

```
 let engine = document.querySelector('select[name=butterbean_stm_car_manager_setting_engine]');
 engine.value = "0";
```

How can I fix this?

HTML:

```
<input type="text" value name="butterbean_stm_car_manager_setting_engine" class="widefat">
```

Comment: attach your html code

Comment: So that means it did not find the element....

Comment: A few things could be wrong here, see: [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14028959)

Comment: what is your selector that complex? why not just use a class or id?

Comment: your selector is looking for a tag `select` with a `name` attribute of `butterbean_stm_car_manager_setting_engine`, you have a `input` tag, not a `select` tag.

Comment: I have `let engine = document.querySelector('select[name=butterbean_stm_car_manager_setting_engine]');` but I need `input`, not `select`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think that the selector works, since you are selecting a `select` tag even though you want to grap the `input` tag. So maybe try

```js
let engine = document.querySelector('input[name=butterbean_stm_car_manager_setting_engine]
```

instead. Though personally I would just target it with the `widefat` class instead since its shorter

Comment: Man, I've answered this question 32 minutes ago in the comments but you are the first one who wrote the answer so I guess I'm going to choose it as correct